# Allowed values for the HTML target attribute

Tags: html, w3c

We are working on a project, where we need to check the possible or universally acceptable values for the target attribute of the HTML anchor tag.

Analysis Done: we have checked the w3c site for the [Target](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) attribute and they have listed a couple of attributes. But apart from the values listed, there are other values also that the target attribute accepts like 'new window', 'new page'  etc.

Is there any site/ reference page by w3c where I can get the acceptable values for these attributes

Comment: FYI, W3Schools isn't the W3C site.

Answer (score 5):

Look at [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) (on the W3 site, not the unrelated W3Schools site). It includes an [index of attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/fullindex.html#attributes-table) where you can see that the value for `target` must be:

> [Valid browsing context name or keyword](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#valid-browsing-context-names-or-keywords)

Which says:

> A valid browsing context name or keyword is any string that is either [a valid browsing context name](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#valid-browsing-context-name) or that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for one of: `_blank`, `_self`, `_parent`, or `_top`.

and

> A valid browsing context name is any string with at least one character that does not start with a U+005F LOW LINE character. (Names starting with an underscore are reserved for special keywords.)

---

In short: It can be `_blank`, `_self`, `_parent`, `_top`, or anything else that does not start with a `_`.